# Merge multiple Slack JSON files

Tags: merge, json, slack, discord

I have recently exported a very large Slack backup which consists of daily JSON files for each channel within the server. I have a process to manually transfer this information across to Discord but to do so for individual JSON files would be very time intensive. It would be easier to merge all JSON files within a folder and upload one per channel.

File structure per folder is by date e.g. 2021-12-03.json, 2021-12-05.json. Here would be an example structure of the file itself which is a consistent array:

```
[
    {
        "bot_id": "B014C6CPY7N",
        "type": "message",
        "text": "User1 has signed up for Associate Membership,Associate Membership with the email <mailto:user1@redacted.net|user1@redacted.net>! Well done team!",
        "user": "U014613HJQJ",
        "ts": "1638698972.000100",
        "team": "T9XQNBRDK",
        "bot_profile": {
            "id": "B014C6CPY7N",
            "app_id": "A024R9PQM",
            "name": "Zapier",
            "icons": {
                "image_36": "https:\/\/slack-files2.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/avatars\/2017-06-20\/redacted_2d5e268a3b71c87f969c_36.png",
                "image_48": "https:\/\/slack-files2.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/avatars\/2017-06-20\/redacted_2d5e268a3b71c87f969c_48.png",
                "image_72": "https:\/\/slack-files2.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/avatars\/2017-06-20\/redacted_2d5e268a3b71c87f969c_72.png"
            },
            "deleted": false,
            "updated": 1590248394,
            "team_id": "T9XQNBRDK"
        }
    },
    {
        "bot_id": "B014C6CPY7N",
        "type": "message",
        "text": "user2 has signed up for Full Membership,Full Membership with the email <mailto:user2@redacted.net|user2@redacted.net>! Well done team!",
        "user": "U014613HJQJ",
        "ts": "1638705446.000100",
        "team": "T9XQNBRDK",
        "bot_profile": {
            "id": "B014C6CPY7N",
            "app_id": "A024R9PQM",
            "name": "Zapier",
            "icons": {
                "image_36": "https:\/\/slack-files2.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/avatars\/2017-06-20\/redacted_2d5e268a3b71c87f969c_36.png",
                "image_48": "https:\/\/slack-files2.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/avatars\/2017-06-20\/redacted_2d5e268a3b71c87f969c_48.png",
                "image_72": "https:\/\/slack-files2.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/avatars\/2017-06-20\/redacted_2d5e268a3b71c87f969c_72.png"
            },
            "deleted": false,
            "updated": 1590248394,
            "team_id": "T9XQNBRDK"
        }
    }
]
```

Are there any software tools or tricks available to merge files like this into one big JSON I can transfer across?

Comment: I have fixed the formatting for you. You have to indent all code or surround it with triple backticks.

Comment: Most json parsers can't deal with gigs of data in one document, so it may actually make more sense to automate your process as a loop over smaller files than as one big push.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this by using the following GitHub project:

https://github.com/mtacnet/json-merger

Cloned the repo, opened up the generator and it seemed to handle around 100 JSON files in one go before it struggled with parsing as per Frank Thomas's comment above.

The merged file imported into the bot I'm using to transfer between Slack and Discord (Slackord2 for anyone interested in that process).